# Can we scrape html elements and add css to them using hpricot gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hpricot

Initially, I have a string of html and text content.

I want to add css stylings to certain html elements from the above string. How can I achieve this using hpricot gem?
I am able to scrap out the html elements by using `each` loop. But how do I take it further?

For eg, I have the following string:

```
"<pre>//code snippet 1</pre><p>Table:</p><table><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

Then, I can access all the `td` elements by using:

```
string.search("//td").each do |ele|
  //some code needed to add css to ele
end
```

Comment: @Jesper I hope my question is clear now. Please let me know if you have any inputs. Thanks.

Comment: You want to add inline styles to certain tags?

Answer (score 0):

Hpricot has been abandoned, so you'd be better off using for example [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org).

I made this example using Nokogiri. You can use the `[]=` method to add arbitrary attributes to a node. We use this to add a `style` attribute.

```
require 'nokogiri'

my_string_fragment = 
  "<pre>//code snippet 1</pre><p>Table:</p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>"

html_fragment = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(my_string_fragment)

html_fragment.css("td").each do |cell|
  cell["style"] = "color: red"
end

puts html_fragment

# Prints this:
#
# <pre>//code snippet 1</pre><p>Table:</p>
# <table>
#   <tbody>
#     <tr>
#       <td style="color: red">1</td>
#       <td style="color: red">2</td>
#       <td style="color: red">3</td>
#     </tr>
#     <tr>
#       <td style="color: red">4</td>
#       <td style="color: red">5</td>
#       <td style="color: red">6</td>
#     </tr>
#   </tbody>
# </table>
```

I used DocumentFragment, because otherwise Nokogiri will make sure that our fragment becomes a full HTML document by adding the `html` tag.

Keep in mind that adding inline CSS styles like this is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hpricot or nokogiri I found a better/cleaner way to achieve what I wanted. I used premailer-rails gem. It requires nokogiri or hpricot gem to work with. But all we need to do is add this gem and it automatically converts external css to inline css.

Reference to the gem: [premailer-rails](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails)